# Grid Won't Show in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, grids-graticules

I have this local map that'd I'm trying to add a grid with decimal points. The internal grid won't show, also when I add the zebra frame the white parts only appear in the corners (as tiny squares). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

[image: screenshot2] [image: screenshot1]

Comment: my guess is, that the CRS is in degrees and not in meters, therefore an interval of 100 is too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you are using 100 degrees in X and Y. I can see that from the projection you are using (EPSG 4326). 
Guessing you want to present a grid in km, you need i) to find out a CRS suitable for it like an UTM projection with meters, then use map units with the interval you want.